# optimized join query for multiple table mysql/php

Tags: mysql, join

I want to merge below queries to reduce execution time, there are total 10 tables from which I want to fetch data & 11th table is on which I can perform `JOIN`. 
I have `datetime` column in each table & I want to fetch data on based of that `datetime` column, data from that table only in which given date condition is matched.

```
$qry1 = "SELECT m.fullName, l.loanAmount AS loanAmount, l.loanStartDate FROM tblMember m
    LEFT JOIN tblLoan l ON m.memberNumber = l.memberNumber
    WHERE l.loanStartDate = '$date' AND l.is_active!=2";

  $qry1_1 = "SELECT m.fullName, li.installment_amount, li.interest_amount , li.installment_added_date, li.installment_comment FROM tblMember m
    LEFT JOIN tblLoan l ON m.memberNumber = l.memberNumber
    LEFT JOIN tblLoanInstallments li ON l.id = li.loan_id
    WHERE li.installment_added_date = '$date' AND li.status=1";

  $qry2 = "SELECT m.fullName, f.fdAmount, f.fdStartDate FROM tblMember m
    LEFT JOIN tblFD f ON m.memberNumber = f.memberNumber
    WHERE  f.fdStartDate = '$date' AND f.is_active = 1";

  $qry2_2 = "SELECT m.fullName, fi.installment_amount, fi.interest_amount, fi.installment_added_date, fi.installment_comment FROM tblMember m
    LEFT JOIN tblFD f ON m.memberNumber = f.memberNumber
    LEFT JOIN tblFDInstallments fi ON f.id = fi.fd_id
    WHERE fi.installment_added_date = '$date' AND fi.status != 2";

  $qry3 = "SELECT m.fullName, shi.saving_amount, shi.installment_amount, shi.interest_amount, shi.installment_added_date, shi.installment_comment FROM tblMember m
    LEFT JOIN tblShare sh ON m.memberNumber = sh.memberNumber
    LEFT JOIN tblShareInstallments shi ON sh.id = shi.s_id
    WHERE shi.installment_added_date = '$date' AND shi.status != 2";

  $qry4 = "SELECT m.fullName, si.saving_amount, si.installment_amount, si.interest_amount, si.installment_added_date, si.installment_comment FROM tblMember m
    LEFT JOIN tblOnlySaving s ON m.memberNumber = s.memberNumber
    LEFT JOIN tblSavingInstallments si ON s.id = si.s_id
    WHERE si.installment_added_date = '$date' AND si.status != 2";

  $qry5 = "SELECT m.fullName, csi.installment_amount, csi.interest_amount, csi.installment_added_date, csi.installment_comment FROM tblMember m
    LEFT JOIN tblCompulsorySaving cs ON m.memberNumber = cs.memberNumber
    LEFT JOIN tblCSSavingInstallments csi ON cs.id = csi.s_id
    WHERE csi.installment_added_date = '$date' AND csi.status != 2";
```

How can I optimized those query? I have tried by JOINing all table but it execute till 6-7 minutes than give error

```
SELECT 
    m.fullName,
    l.loanAmount AS loanAmount,
    l.loanStartDate,
    li.installment_amount,
    li.interest_amount,
    li.installment_added_date,
    f.fdAmount,
    f.fdStartDate,
    fi.installment_amount,
    fi.interest_amount,
    fi.installment_added_date,
    shi.saving_amount,
    shi.installment_amount,
    shi.interest_amount,
    shi.installment_added_date,
    shi.installment_comment,
    si.saving_amount,
    si.installment_amount,
    si.interest_amount,
    si.installment_added_date,
    si.installment_comment,
    csi.installment_amount,
    csi.interest_amount,
    csi.installment_added_date,
    csi.installment_comment
FROM
    tblMember m
        LEFT JOIN
    tblLoan l ON m.memberNumber = l.memberNumber
        LEFT JOIN
    tblLoanInstallments li ON l.id = li.loan_id
        LEFT JOIN
    tblFD f ON m.memberNumber = f.memberNumber
        LEFT JOIN
    tblFDInstallments fi ON f.id = fi.fd_id
        LEFT JOIN
    tblShare sh ON m.memberNumber = sh.memberNumber
        LEFT JOIN
    tblShareInstallments shi ON sh.id = shi.s_id
        LEFT JOIN
    tblOnlySaving s ON m.memberNumber = s.memberNumber
        LEFT JOIN
    tblSavingInstallments si ON s.id = si.s_id
        LEFT JOIN
    tblCompulsorySaving cs ON m.memberNumber = cs.memberNumber
        LEFT JOIN
    tblCSSavingInstallments csi ON cs.id = csi.s_id
WHERE
        (MONTH(l.loanStartDate) = '5'
        AND YEAR(l.loanStartDate) = '2018'
        AND l.is_active != 2)
        OR (MONTH(li.installment_added_date) = '5'
        AND YEAR(li.installment_added_date) = '2018'
        AND li.status = 1)
        OR (MONTH(f.fdStartDate) = '5'
        AND YEAR(f.fdStartDate) = '2018'
        AND f.is_active != 2)
        OR (MONTH(fi.installment_added_date) = '5'
        AND YEAR(fi.installment_added_date) = '2018'
        AND fi.status = 1)
        OR (MONTH(shi.installment_added_date) = '5'
        AND YEAR(shi.installment_added_date) = '2018'
        AND shi.status = 1)
        OR (MONTH(si.installment_added_date) = '5'
        AND YEAR(si.installment_added_date) = '2018'
        AND si.status = 1)
        OR (MONTH(csi.installment_added_date) = '5'
        AND YEAR(csi.installment_added_date) = '2018'
        AND csi.status = 1)
```

`WHERE` condition is different in both queries because previously I am giving to-from date & now I want to change it to month.
All tables have approx 10000 records & the query can have 1000-2000 RESULT rows

Comment: You did not write what is the error you were given

Comment: can you prepend an explain clause before the select statement?

Comment: @rai I am not getting you, what do you mean?

Comment: @avi you may refer to this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

Smells like "over-normalization".  If all (or most) of the columns in the secondary tables exist for all rows of `tblMember`, then put them all in the `tblMember`.

Also, try to avoid un-sargable constructs such as

```
      AND MONTH(l.loanStartDate) = '5'
      AND  YEAR(l.loanStartDate) = '2018'
```

Instead, consider using a `DATE` datatype and do

```
     AND  loanStartDate >= '2018-05-01'
     AND  loanStartDate  < '2018-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Or, if you only need to store year and month, then store them (as `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` or `DECIMAL(6.0)`:  201805 and use

```
     AND loanStartDate = 201805
```